# How to avoid inflated/bogus settlement demands in auto accident in California

Tags: california, insurance

Involved in an accident in California, and the other party has hired an atty to request policy limits. Other party was not seriously injured (paramedics left after thoroughly inspecting the other party for 5 minutes and getting the signature of the other party for refusal of ambulance and further medical treatment). Police left after 3 minutes after seeing no one was seriously hurt and getting consent of both drivers.

In the past, experienced a case where GEICO just paid out the full policy limit right away, even though other party's total medical bills and treatment were less than 1/10th of that (minor injuries). Other party in that case had radio silence for a year and ignored GEICO's attempts to reach out, then suddenly hired an atty. Other party's attorney tacked on bogus items to the claim to make it ***exactly*** the policy limit and GEICO did not bother to fight, even though some items would have clearly had no evidence to substantiate them.

Am concerned that this case might turn into last time again. How can I encourage GEICO to fight bogus claim items assuming that I give them permission to disclose? Is this just a thing where they don't bother, simply pay the limits and move on, since they'll just collect higher premiums anyway? Does paying the full policy limits increase the premium substantially?

Comment: Why do you want them to fight it? They are the ones who need to decide if the cost of fighting it is less than the cost of paying out, weighted by the chances of winning. They may be well aware of the inflated claims but they know they'll never counter-sue and win to get their fees back so they pay something anyway...

Answer (score 1):

### Read your policy

Almost certainly this is not something over which you have any influence or control. When you buy insurance one of the powers you give your insurer is the right for *them* to decide who to settle (or fight) claims.